# Action Script Constants for HTTP Status Codes

Tags: actionscript-3, http-status-codes

I am calling a Java REST web service from the front end code, which is written in Action Script 3, and then I check the response status, which can be 200, 500 etc.

I was wondering if there are some constants defined in as3 for these codes, it would make my class more readable (I googled it and couldn't find anything).

Comment: I don't think that AS has something like this, but why not creating yours ?

Comment: ...or use a third-party solution, however I don't really see the point
https://www.flox.cc/sdk/as3/apidoc/com/gamua/flox/utils/HttpStatus.html